# Trimming parts of a word but each word is different size

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with values like this:

```
book;65
book;1000
table;66
restaurant;1202
park;2
park;44444
```

Is there a way using postgres sql to remove everything, regardless of the length of the word, that includes the semi-colon and everything after it?

I plan on doing a query that goes something like this after I figure this out:

```
select col1, modified_col_1 
from table_1
```

--modified is without the semi-colon and everything after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `strpos()` for this:

```
select col1, substring(col1, 1, strpos(col1, ';') - 1) as modified_col_1
```

The above will give an error if there are values *without* a `;`

Another option would be to split the string into an array and then just pick the first element:

```
select (string_to_array(col1, ';'))[1]
from table_1
```

This will also work if no `;` is present